# How to get the response from Faraday get request with token authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faraday

I'm using Faraday with token authentication and unable to configure it to get the response.

So far i'm writing it like this

```
conn = Faraday.new(url: url) do |faraday|
 faraday.token_auth(ENV.fetch('API_TOKEN'))
 faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
end
```

And when i'm using the `conn` object to get the response it is responding in a different manner like this

```
conn.response    
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1+))
```

I'm not sure what i am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday#usage) mentioned how to get response. So i configured it like this for the url:

```
url = https://some-api.com/products/1231/other_part_of_url
base_url = https://some-api.com
path = products/1231/other_part_of_url

conn = Faraday.new(url: base_url) do |faraday|
 faraday.headers['Authorization'] = ENV.fetch('API_TOKEN')
 faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
end

response = conn.get(path)
response.body
```

Also i have moved the token to headers because of when using `faraday.token_auth(ENV.fetch('API_TOKEN'))`
it is adding additional string before the token like `token token - 2342342` which is invalid for the api i'm getting the data.